# Merge [uncaught-typeerror] into [typeerror]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are currently 1.6k questions tagged [typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeerror) with 4 followers and only 145 questions tagged [uncaught-typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncaught-typeerror) with 0 followers. [uncaught-typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncaught-typeerror) also doesn't have a tag wiki. Both these tags refer to basically the same thing, the only difference is that [uncaught-typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncaught-typeerror) applies only to JavaScript, whereas [typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeerror) applies to both JavaScript and Python.

The word "Uncaught" is always present in error message if the error has not been caught using `try...catch` statement. I don't see any point in using different tags based on whether error has been caught or not.

So, should [uncaught-typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncaught-typeerror) be merged into [typeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeerror)?